# Rendering React component issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble rendering. Here is how I set up my files so far. First here is the app.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import MainPage from './MainPage';

export class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MainPage />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the second associated file called index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { App } from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Lastly in the MainPage component I'm importing this:

```
import App from "./app";
```

Is there a reason why this doesn't work with the file structure set as is? I know I can just put the ReacDOM.render in the app.js file as an alternative, but due to unit testing purposes, the file structure has to be similar to this.

Comment: In `MainPage` your are importing with lowercase "a"

Comment: Why are you importing `App.js` in `MainPage`?

Answer (score 0):

You have already imported `App.js` and rendering it via `ReactDOM`. You don't need to import it in `MainPage` as `App` is the parent of your `MainPage`. Currently your import statement in `MainPage` is wrong. Even if it was correct, you would get into cyclic imports. `App` -> `MainApp` -> `App` -> `MainPage` and so on.

`MainPage` should render your usual content. Change `MainPage` to something:

```
import React from 'react';
export default class MainPage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is Main Page</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Note **default** after the export.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to import the default export of the file app.js with this :

```
import App from "./app";
```

But you're using a simple export in you app.js file :

```
export class App extends React.Component {
```

So to import this class the syntax is (like in your index.js) :

```
 import { App } from "./App";
```

Btw in your case you're importing a parent component in the child, you shouldn't do that.